# Java UI Rendering Model using Threads. Volatile vs Synchronized Block for the InputState

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, rendering, volatile

The issue.

The **UI Thread** processes Key/Pointer events and write them in a class named InputState.

The Rendering thread reads from the InputState and updates its state continuously.

I see 3 solutions

1. use **`synchronized`** keyword on all get/set methods in the `InputState`. But that means every single time `Render` threads check for events possibilities (about 50 times per loop), it must acquire a lock. Not very efficient but allows for fine multi threading between `UIThread` and `Render` thread.
2. Synchronize on the `InputState` single reference. Render thread synchronizes on the whole object and does its 50 gets checks sequentially while holding the lock and then releases the lock.
3. Have 2 instances of the `InputState`. Let's say 1 and 2. Rendering thread access the "live" (InputState1) with the volatile keyword. None of the `InputState` method are synchronized.
   When a new event is processed by the UI thread, the UI thread updates the shadow copy of the `InputState`, InputState2, then once finished, updates the live volalite reference. That crucial operation is atomic right? Now Render thread sees InputState2 as "live". InputState1 is now the shadow InputState. BUT!
   UI Thread must make sure of something. UIThread must now wait that the rendering thread exits any methods before using it again. Because the Render thread might be sooo slow that it gets stuck in a get method in InputState1 while 2 events are processed in a Row by **UIThread**. might it not?  ***I am not yet sure how to fix this. Hence my question here.*** I could use a 3rd InputState instead of 2 and rotate them while checking the volatile loop count of the rendering thread.

Which is the best option in your opinion?

Comment: Probably option 2.  There is no avoiding synchronization when communicating between threads.  The other options both are more complex and add more overhead.

Comment: I found some relevant info here http://blog.slapware.eu/game-engine/programming/multithreaded-renderloop-part1/